# C# Parsing a webpage's source

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, data-mining

Among the wall of text that is a pages source; I need to get the video_id,l and t without the quotes so for a section like this.

"video_id": "lUoiKMxSUCw", "l": 105, "sk": "-2fL6AANk__E49CRzF6_Q8F7yBPWdb9QR", "fmt_map": "35/640000/9/0/115,34/0/9/0/115,5/0/7/0/0", "t": "vjVQa1PpcFMbYtdhqxUip5Vtm856lwh7lXZ6lH6nZAg=",

i need the following

lUoiKMxSUCw

105

vjVQa1PpcFMbYtdhqxUip5Vtm856lwh7lXZ6lH6nZAg=

i was told to use "regular expressions" but I'm not to sure how to use them. any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex to use could be:

```
\"video_id\":\s*\"(?<videoID>.*?)\"(?:.*?)\"l\":\s*(?<l>.*?),(?:.*?)\"t\":\s*\"(?<t>.*?)\"
```

Here's some sample code to get you up and running:

```
string sample = "\"video_id\": \"lUoiKMxSUCw\", \"l\": 105, \"sk\": \"-2fL6AANk__E49CRzF6_Q8F7yBPWdb9QR\", \"fmt_map\": \"35/640000/9/0/115,34/0/9/0/115,5/0/7/0/0\", \"t\": \"vjVQa1PpcFMbYtdhqxUip5Vtm856lwh7lXZ6lH6nZAg=\",";
string regPattern = "\\\"video_id\\\":\\s*\\\"(?<videoID>.*?)\\\"(?:.*?)\\\"l\\\":\\s*(?<l>.*?),(?:.*?)\\\"t\\\":\\s*\\\"(?<t>.*?)\\\"";
Regex reg = new Regex(regPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (reg.IsMatch(sample))
{
    Match m = reg.Match(sample);
    GroupCollection gColl = m.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine("VideoID:{0}", gColl["videoID"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("l:{0}", gColl["l"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("t:{0}", gColl["t"].Value);
}
```

Don't forget to import "System.Text.RegularExpressions". ;-)

Comment: care to break down the provided code so i can understand what makes it work more.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sites good for learning, but if you expect code to do your work, sorry..

this looks like a good start : [Regular Expressions Usage in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx)

And also [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If the order is always the same, you could use this regular expression:

```
"video_id"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*,\s*"l"\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:,\s*"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*,\s*"t"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

Otherwise you should grab each entry in a list and then pick the ones out you need.